# How to filter away all the methods except an exact string in the Eclipse outline view

Tags: regex, eclipse

The tile is the exact question.
I can click on the outline > filter and I assume I can enter a req expression which filters the elements captured by this expression.

**Question:** What should I put in the Filter textbox to filter all the elements except for example "toString()"?

Comment: Try `\b(?!toString\()\w+\(`

Comment: Which editor's Outline View? It makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Set focus on Java Editor. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>. By default `toString()` method will not be shown. If you want all super classes methods to be displayed then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> one more time.

Don't use **Outline View** instead use **Quick outline** command (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>) for this.